# Why has the price of laser eye surgery not changed?

Tags: inflation

Within the USA, I have long heard rumors that since laser eye corrective surgery is not often included in insurance plans or subsidized by governments, the price of laser eye has remained relatively stable over the past few decades even though it is a very complicated process.

On the other hand, simple medical processes (eg. blood tests, x-rays) keep increasing in price every year. This is because these are often included in insurance plans, subsidized by governments, etc.

Are there any economic research papers that document these kinds of arguments for price inflation for subsidized/non-subsidized medical services from an empirical data perspective? Are there any economic research papers that document these kinds of arguments for price inflation for subsidized/non-subsidized medical services from a theoretical perspective?

Comment: What country are you talking about? Also what evidence you have that the price did not change?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This was the USA. I have no evidence, thats why I said I heard rumors.